# Пунктуация в предложении с вставной конструкцией

Tags: недопустимая-метка, вставная-конструкция

> Он думал, что навыки, которые передал
> ему отец — чтение, письмо, охота, —
> имели наивысшую ценность.
>
> Он думал, что навыки, которые передал
> ему отец, — чтение, письмо, охота —
> имели наивысшую ценность.

Где должна быть запятая: после слова *отец* или после слова *охота*?

Ведь если вставку уберем, то запятая в обоих случаях будет после слова *отец*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, чт здесь можно применить **обособление приложения по типу вставной конструкции**: Он думал, что навыки, которые передал ему отец, — чтение, письмо, охота, — имели наивысшую ценность. Обратим внимание на то, что такое приложение читается как вставка. Кроме того, другие способы оформления не передают структуру предложения достаточно наглядно.

В этом случае говорится, что вторая запятая ставится для симметрии, например: Когда Косте пошёл девятый годок, –  я же в ту пору уже невестой была, – повезла я его по всем гимназиям.

Comment: >В этом случае говорится, что вторая запятая ставится для симметрии, например: Когда Косте пошёл девятый годок, – я же в ту пору уже невестой была, – повезла я его по всем гимназиям. 
  
Это где ж такое "говорится"? Здесь совершенно другой случай. 

Ясно, Голуб резвится. "ЕГЭ 2015. Русский язык без репетитора. Сдаем без проблем!" п. 299 - примечание.

Но даже если принять её трактовку (что весьма спорно), то у Чехова "для симметрии" поставлена первая запятая, а не вторая - это раз. И два, не уточняется является эта "симметричная" запятая обязательной.

Comment: @Vera, вот по этому поводу ответ грамотной "справки" (сам вопрос привести не могу, он слишком длинный)

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Согласно правилам современного русского языка запятая и тире как единый знак при обособлении вставных конструкций не используются. Поэтому пунктуацию в приведённых Вами примерах можно объяснить только волей автора (или переводчика).

http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_256264

Answer (score 3):

После слова слова "отец".

*Он думал, что навыки, которые передал ему отец, — чтение, письмо, охота — имели наивысшую ценность.*

Смотрите структуру. Расшифровка (чтение, письмо, охота) относится к слову "навыки", т.е. зависимое предложение ограничивается словами "которые передал ему отец". За пятая должна "закрыть" это подчиненное предложение, а постановка её после "охота" ничем не мотивированна.  
А вот для предложения, в котором подобный список относился бы к слову внутри подчиненного  предложения, конструкция была бы иная. 
*Он думал, что навыки, которые передали ему старшие — отец, дед, дядя, — имели наивысшую ценность.*
Тут логично бы запятую вообще после второго тире ставить, но в подобных случаях она переносится вперед, поскольку запятая всегда по соображениям наглядности стоит сразу за последним словом (исключение - встреча с закрывающими кавычкой или скобкой, а так же точкой поле сокращения).

А вообще во избежание подобных сложностей такие конструкции лучше оформлять через скобки или (если позволяет синтаксис) через двоеточие - как перечисление.

*Он думал, что навыки, которые передал ему отец: чтение, письмо, охота - имели наивысшую ценность.*

(Правда, тут всегда возникает вопрос, насколько такая конструкция удовлетворяет понятию перечисления с предшествующим обобщающим словом, но тут похоже, что вполне удовлетворяет).

Comment: Конструкция нестандартная, мне, к примеру, не приходилось встречать в учебниках этот вариант: сущ.+ определительное придаточное или оборот + ряд приложений, при этом рядом не заканчивается предложение. Поэтому вряд ли соотносить этот пример с уже имеющимися решениями, если только не найдется именно такой случай. Итак, мы имеем существительное после которого стоят ДВЕ ОБОСОБЛЕННЫЕ КОНСТРУКЦИИ (придаточное + однородный ряд), а затем продолжается предложение. И они должны быть закрыты запятой, иначе этот ряд приложений просто зависает в пространстве.